# Combine two csv rows into one row

Tags: python, csv, awk

I'm trying to combine two rows of a csv file into a single row.

csv file:

```
"Operations=5009.0,AverageLatency(us)=714.4248352964663,MinLatency(us)=300.0,MaxLatency(us)=173567.0,95thPercentileLatency(us)=1216.0,99thPercentileLatency(us)=2645.0,Return=5009"
"Operations=4991.0,AverageLatency(us)=831.4189541174113,MinLatency(us)=370.0,MaxLatency(us)=25999.0,95thPercentileLatency(us)=1495.0,99thPercentileLatency(us)=2857.0,Return=4991"
```

expected output:

```
"Operations=5009.0,AverageLatency(us)=714.4248352964663,MinLatency(us)=300.0,MaxLatency(us)=173567.0,95thPercentileLatency(us)=1216.0,99thPercentileLatency(us)=2645.0,Return=5009","Operations=4991.0,AverageLatency(us)=831.4189541174113,MinLatency(us)=370.0,MaxLatency(us)=25999.0,95thPercentileLatency(us)=1495.0,99thPercentileLatency(us)=2857.0,Return=4991"
```

I tried this:

```
awk 'NR%2{printf $0" ";next;}1' file.csv
```

But its does not print entire first row.

```
"Operations=5009.0,AverageLatency(us)=714.4248352964663,MinLatency(us)=300.0,MaxLatency(us)=173567.0,95thPercentileLatency(us)=1216.0,99thPercenti "Operations=4991.0,AverageLatency(us)=831.4189541174113,MinLatency(us)=370.0,MaxLatency(us)=25999.0,95thPercentileLatency(us)=1495.0,99thPercentileLatency(us)=2857.0,Return=4991"
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: @Whitecat I'm using python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the example you described, the following code should do the job:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=","}{if(NR%2==1){val=$0;}else{print val,$0}}' inputFile
```

Store the content of odd lines in a variable and print the content of this variable together with the current line in even rows.

Output:

```
"Operations=5009.0,AverageLatency(us)=714.4248352964663,MinLatency(us)=300.0,MaxLatency(us)=173567.0,95thPercentileLatency(us)=1216.0,99thPercentileLatency(us)=2645.0,Return=5009","Operations=4991.0,AverageLatency(us)=831.4189541174113,MinLatency(us)=370.0,MaxLatency(us)=25999.0,95thPercentileLatency(us)=1495.0,99thPercentileLatency(us)=2857.0,Return=4991"
```

If there were only two lines in your input file, there is a more complicated way to solve the problem (which I first came up with):

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=""; FS="\n"; OFS=",";}{print $1,$2;}' inputFile
```

This code interprets linebreaks ("\n") as field seperators. That is, two lines in your `inputFile` appear as two columns of the same data set. (We need the `RS=""` to overwrite its default value.)
In the output, this linebreak has to be replaced by a comma (`OFS=","`).

Comment: Thanks! But still the first row is not complete.

Comment: @Araz: When I run the command here, I get your expected output. What are you missing? By the way, your command yields the expected output, too (except for the missing "," as field separator). May be there is something wrong with your display Have you tried writing the output to a file? I have added my output to the answer...

Comment: There was an issue in my input file. Just solved. Thanks.